# Asp.Net MVC 5 Host on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-5

can anyone please tell me whether  a asp.net mvc 5  web application can be hosted on IIS 7.5?seems has this issue:HTTP Error 503.
and the IIS application pool was stopped when request this web.

it's very strange,when I change website application pool named "A" to another named "B"("B" is an app pool for an asp.net mvc4 web application), then the site run well."A" is the same setting as "B".not really know what had happened.is related section of the web.config ?please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found it was caused by permission problems creating the user profile in C:\Users. I gave ApplicationPoolIdentity full permissions to the C:\Users folder, started the site and everything worked, the profile must have been created properly, and my site worked as it should. I then removed access to C:\Users from ApplicationPoolIdentity.

[Site wont start on local using ApplicationPoolIdentity, only when using NetworkService: "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992590/site-wont-start-on-local-using-applicationpoolidentity-only-when-using-networks/)